# jQuery Mobile form ajax post not working?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm currently creating a simple jQuery Mobile sign in page. Here's my code:

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        die("hello");
    } 

    ?>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form method="post">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" />
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
</div>
```

Whenever I type in a username and password, using firebug, I can tell that the correct post was sent, however, the page that is returned through ajax to load into the page does not have the `die("hello")` in it. It is just the same page that I entered the login information on.

Am I using jQuery Mobile's form system wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider turning off Ajax, while you are troubleshooting your form submission.  The Ajax handling of form submissions inside JQuery Mobile is implemented automatically to create a smooth transition between the form and the result.  Details, [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/forms/forms-sample.html).   To submit a form without Ajax, you can either disable Ajax form handling globally, or per form via the

```
data-ajax="false"
```

attribute.  Or, globally,

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```